# Solutions : Henry Law

Tags: solutions

In below solution why the moles are considered half as their is nothing clearly specified in question. I mean it is not given that that mole fraction we get is for litre water.
[image: Question]

Comment: They just wrote the multiplication by liters in an unusual way. You are going from molarity to moles, which means multiplying by .5 L or 1/2 L. @user560199

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the question closely, it states in the equation, moles per litre. The reason the moles are divided by two is the fact you need to find the moles of CO2 in 500 ml and not 1000 ml.